# Where's the BIOS on an Intel Mac?

Tags: mac, bios

When I use my laptop, I have no trouble at all accessing the BIOS and changing things like the boot order.

However I recently got an iMac and have found that not only do the usual keys not get me to the BIOS, but when I find one that gets me to a boot menu (holding <kbd>option</kbd> when booting up) it won't recognize my USB boot drive of Ubuntu!

How can I access the BIOS menu like I could in a PC?

Comment: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-get-to-the-bios-in-mac-os-x

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no BIOS on a Mac. It uses [EFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface), which can be configured from within OS X e.g. using `bless` from the command line.

You are able to boot from external USB drives that [satisfy some requirements](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948).

There are some [key combinations](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533) that change the boot sequence, but there is no real boot menu.

---

Change the permanent preferred boot device in *System Preferences* on OS X or *Boot Camp* settings on Windows.

[image]

---

If you want more than what's available out of the box, you need to e.g. use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @grawity What exactly was your edit referring to? Partially reverted because unclear (did you mean bless?), and conflict with an edit of mine.

Comment: I was adding a note about the ability to reconfigure EFI from the booted operating system ("EFI variables" on standard UEFI, although Apple obviously chose its own path), as opposed to BIOS which has to be managed through a pre-boot settings screen. This could be why Apple left out the pre-boot settings completely; it's all integrated.

Comment: Actually newer Macs which can run windows do have BIOS. It's just that it's there only for compatibility with older windows versions that don't support UEFI and if I remember correctly, there's no way to access it.

Comment: @AndrejaKo AFAIK, BIOS is only emulated on top of EFI in a minimal way to support Windows.

Comment: Could we update this answer from rEFIt to [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)?