# What motherboard does a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013) have?

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, macbook-pro-retina

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013). I'd like to know what type of motherboard I have so I can figure out if it's using [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) or [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS).

I've tried `cmd+f`ing through the specs for `EFI`, `BIOS`, and `motherboard` but didn't find anything.

- How do I learn about what kind of motherboard is on my laptop?

**Note:**

I'm aware there are folks who already know that [Intel Macs are EFI based](http://refit.sourceforge.net/). I'm curious how one would go about discovering what my motherboard is, which is a not the same question being explored [here](https://superuser.com/q/373151/277471). What tools are used, what are you looking for in specs, a link to a reference is appreciated but I'm more interested in how one is to use that reference to discover what type of motherboard is being used on a Apple computer.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/373151/wheres-the-bios-on-an-intel-mac

Comment: This is not a duplicate, see edit.

Comment: Knowing WHY you need this information could be helpful. Laptop mainboards are usually identified by a part number rather than a model number, as they are typically unique to that specific laptop model and are not found (or available) anywhere else. The way they are typically identified for replacement is by the laptop they go into, as will likely be the case here. In other words, the mainboard for the late 2013 MacBook Pro 13" is the MacBook Pro 13" Retina laptop mainboard.

Comment: Taken from the [Arch installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide) `If UEFI mode is enabled on an UEFI motherboard, Archiso will boot Arch Linux accordingly via systemd-boot.` So I'm curious if my macbook is a UEFI motherboard.

Comment: Then make that your question. We can only really answer the question that is asked, and as it is asked, this question is basically a duplicate as it has been flagged.

Comment: To @Ramhound, Moderator Impersonator, Run5k, music2myear and Paul:  what part of the linked questions illustrates how to figure out what motherboard is on my apple machine? How is this question `How can I access the BIOS menu like I could in a PC?` a duplicate of `How do I learn about what kind of motherboard is on my laptop?` ? They are different questions. One is requesting a series of commands performed at boot time to enter the bios menu; another is requesting help reading through specs to figure out what motherboard is on a laptop.

Answer (score -1):

Specs for every Apple product: http://www.everymac.com

Comment: You do not provide an answer to the question. OP asks the model of his MBP motherboard, you provide a link to (presumably) all MBP models. Edit your answer as @FleetCommand suggested.

Comment: As others have said providing a link with no context is not helpful. It is helpful to always quote the most relevant part of an important link. Please refer to the [How to Answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) help section for more info.

Comment: There is not a mainboard identifier listed in this parts catalog for that system.